# How many days will it take me to earn a certain sum of money (given a certain probability)?

Tags: probability

Suppose I want to earn $7000$. How many days will it take me to earn it, if there is an $80\%$ chance I will make $500$ on a particular day and a $20\%$ chance I will lose $1500$ on the same day?

My solution is $\displaystyle\frac{7000}{(500\times 80\%)+(-1500\times20\%)}=70$ days

Is this correct?

PS: I trade in the stock market

Comment: This question is a little unclear. Are you trying to say that everyday you have an 80% chance to make 500 and a 20% chance to lose 1500, or is this in a particular day?

Comment: You are asking for $E(T_{14})$ where $T_{14}=\inf\{n\geqslant0\mid S_n\geqslant14\}$ for the random walk with steps $+1$ with probability $p=\frac45$ and $-3$ with probability $1-p$. Since there are only $+1$ positive steps, this is $E(T_{14})=14\cdot E(T_1)$, where $T_{1}=\inf\{n\geqslant0\mid S_n\geqslant1\}$. Conditioning on the first step, one gets $E(T_1)=1+(1-p)E(T_4)$, hence $E(T_1)=1+4(1-p)E(T_1)$, $E(T_1)=1/(4p-3)$, and finally $E(T_{14})=14/(4p-3)$, that is, $E(T_{14})=70$. A more direct route, once we know that $E(T_n)=n\cdot E(T_1)$ for every $n$, is to note that ...

Comment: ... by the law of large numbers, $S_n/n\to m=1\cdot p+(-3)\cdot(1-p)$ hence $T_n/n\to1/m$ when $n\to\infty$, almost surely. Assuming the convergence holds in $L^1$ as well, one gets $E(T_n/n)\to1/m$, hence $E(T_1)=1/m$ and $E(T_n)=n/m$ for every $n$, qed. Note that the hypothesis that one must hit $+1$ then $+2$, then $+3$, and so on, to reach the given positive level $+14$, is crucial in the proof (and in the result).

Comment: @NoySoffer It's on a daily basis

Answer (score 1):

The situation is a little more complicated than that. In particular you don't have any certainty. Given that in average you earn $100\$$ a day, it should take you in average $70$ days to get to $7000\$$. But you can experience sensible ups and down during this period and you cannot bound the losses that you could incur.

To make things a little more formal, you could define $$X_i = \begin{cases} 1  & \text{with probability $p = 0.8$} \\ 0 & \text{with probability $1-p = 0.2$}\end{cases}$$ a bernoulli variable that represents your winning or losing in a single day; then define $$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n 500X_i - 1500(1-X_i) = 2000\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - 1500n$$ as your cumulative gain.

Assuming the $X_i$ independent, you get that $Y_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ has a binomial distribution $Y_n \sim Bi(p,n)$. So $S_n = 2000Y_n - 1500n$

At this point you can calculate $$P(S_n \ge 7000 ) = P(Y_n \ge \frac 72 + \frac 34 n) = \sum_{i =\left\lceil \frac 72 + \frac 34 n\right\rceil  }^n \binom{n}{i}0.8^i\cdot0.2^{n-i}$$

which is the probability of you having more than $7000\$$ on day $n$.

Now define $$\tau = \inf\{n > 0: S_n \ge 7000\}$$ which is a stopping time with respect to  $\mathcal F$, the sigma algebra generated by $S_n$: $\mathcal F = (\mathcal F_t)_{t \ge 0}$ with $\mathcal F_t = \sigma((S_n)_{n \le t})$. $\tau$ represents the first time you ever gained more than $7000\$$

The distribution of $\tau$ can give you lots of information on what your future capital will look like.
I am having a little trouble calculating the distribution of $\tau$ and calculating it's expected value though.. I'll have to think about this :-)

Answer (score 1):

I also have $n=70$. I have done more basic calculations to get the result. For the following I use some statements which are related to the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). After $n$ periods there are $n \choose x$ ways of loosing $x$ times and winning $n-x$ times. The probability of loosing $x$ times and winning $(n-x)$ times is  $0.8^x\cdot 0.2^{n-x}$.

The result after winning $x$ times and loosing $(n-x)$ times in one specific way is $x\cdot 500-(n-x)\cdot 1500$. In total the expected value is

$$E(x)=\sum_{x=0}^n {n \choose x} 0.8^x\cdot 0.2^{n-x}\cdot \left(x \cdot  500-(n-x)\cdot 1500\right)$$
$$E(x)=\sum_{x=0}^n {n \choose x} 0.8^x\cdot 0.2^{n-x}\cdot \left(2000\cdot x- 1500 \cdot n \right)$$
$$E(x)=-{1500\cdot n\underbrace{\sum_{x=0}^n {n \choose x} 0.8^x\cdot 0.2^{n-x}}_{=1}}+ 2000 \cdot \underbrace{\sum_{x=0}^n x \cdot {n \choose x} 0.8^x\cdot 0.2^{n-x} }_{=E(x)=n\cdot 0.8} $$

- The [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) says that

  $ (a+b)^n=\sum_{x=0}^{n}{{n \choose x}\cdot a^{x}\cdot b^{n-x}} $

  with $a=0.8$ an $b=0.2$ the sum is just $(0.8+0.2)^n=1$
- The expectation value, $E(x)$,  of the binomial distribution is $n\cdot
     p=n\cdot 0.8$

Thus we have

$E(x)=-1500\cdot n+2000\cdot 0.8\cdot n=7000$

$E(x)=-1500\cdot n+1600\cdot n=7000$

$E(x)=100\cdot n=7000$

$n=\frac{7000}{100}=70$

Comment: This solves for $n$ the equation $E(X_n)=7000$ while the question asks to find the mean of $T_{7000}=\inf\{n\mid X_n=7000\}$. That the two results are identical is not always true and uses crucially the hypothesis that the legal negative steps are all multiples of the only positive legal step.

Comment: @Did Quote:"... uses crucially the hypothesis that the legal negative steps are all multiples of the only positive legal step." I don´t think that I have done this. Could you explain more detailed what you mean by this ?

Comment: As I said, and as is written explicitely in my previous comment, we are asked to compute $E(T_{7000})$ and you are solving $E(X_n)=7000$. Why would these be equivalent? (I did not say that you failed to use the hypothesis stated in my comment, simply that you proved another result.)

Comment: @Did Interesting comment. I think it takes a while to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your solution seems alright, albeit you need some explanation. The expected profit in one days is:

$$E[x] = 500\cdot p(500) + (-1500) \cdot p(-1500) = 500 \cdot \frac 45 - 1500 \frac 15 = 100$$

So if you are expected to make $100$ dollars per day, you need $70$ days to earn $7000$ dollars.

Comment: This solves for $n$ the equation $E(X_n)=7000$ while the question asks to find the mean of $T_{7000}=\inf\{n\mid X_n=7000\}$. That the two results are identical is not always true and uses crucially the hypothesis that the legal negative steps are all multiples of the only positive legal step.